# How do I add all the font-faces available for a specific Google Font?(in JS)

Tags: javascript, html, web, fonts, google-fonts

I'm looking for a way to generate all possible Google Fonts URLs for a specific font. I want to include **all available styles** (
italic, normal) and **weights** (e.g 400–800).

I'm working on an image editor, and I need to load every font from a font-family when a user selects a font.

Currently, I'm using [the fontsource API](https://api.fontsource.org/v1/fonts) to retrieve data on the available fonts and I try to generate the **google CSS links** from that data,

E.g

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open%20Sans:ital,wght@0,300..800;1,300..800
```

but the function I wrote sometimes generate **invalid links** and I'm not sure it includes all possibles styles/weights.

Example API result:

```
{
 "id": "open-sans",
 "family": "Open Sans",
 "subsets": [
  "cyrillic",
  "cyrillic-ext",
  "greek",
  "greek-ext",
  "hebrew",
  "latin",
  "latin-ext",
  "vietnamese"
 ],
 "weights": [
  300,
  400,
  500,
  600,
  700,
  800
 ],
 "styles": [
  "italic",
  "normal"
 ],
 "defSubset": "latin",
 "variable": true,
 "lastModified": "2022-09-22",
 "category": "sans-serif",
 "license": "OFL-1.1",
 "type": "google"
}
```

Here is my current code, do you know a better solution for this? Thanks

```
    function generateGoogleFontURL(font) {
  const formattedFontFamily = font.family.replace(/\s+/g, "+")
  if (font.weights.length == 0) {
    return [`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}`]
  }
  if (!font.variable) {
      if (font.styles.includes("italic")) {
        return font.weights.map(x => `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}:ital,wght@0,${x};1,${x}`)
      }
      return [`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}:wght@${font.weights.join(';')}`]
  }
  if (font.weights.length > 1) {
    const minWeight = font.weights[0]
    const maxWeight = font.weights[font.weights.length - 1]
    if (font.styles.includes("italic")) {
        return [`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}:ital,wght@0,${minWeight}..${maxWeight};1,${minWeight}..${maxWeight}`]
    }
    else {
      return [`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}:wght@${minWeight}..${maxWeight}`]
    }
  }    
  if (font.styles.includes("italic")) {
      return [`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}:ital,wght@0,${font.weights[0]};1,${font.weights[0]}`]
  }
  return [`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}:wght@${font.weights[0]}`]
}
```

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question and revised your description. Please check the revision if I got anything wrong. There is actually a little typo: it should be "BASE_URL" in uppercase. Can you provide a font family example where you got an invalid URL? Just replace the added "Open Sans" example - which is actually working

Comment: Yeah sorry I had to replace the actual google url manually because the post was getting flagged as spam by stackoverflow otherwise. I also slightly improved the code but I'm still not sure it's including all possible variations.

After multiple tries I think most of the errors may have come from some rate-limiting on google side, because the errors seemed to be quite random after a few hundred fonts loaded.

Comment: thanks for updating your code but it's still important to give us a font-family example where the generated URL was invalid (Open Sans actually works pretty well). Ideally you should wrap your code in a running snippet including the js retrieving the API data (e.g via fetch())

Comment: Why would you use fontsource instead of just... using Google fonts? Go to https://fonts.google.com/, find the family you want, select all the styles and weights you need, and.... done? Copy the HTML for the stylesheet and use that in your own HTML file or template, or copy the CSS @import rule and add that to your own CSS.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I want to make every single google font available to my users

Comment: That's what https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current function should actually work.
But there are some issues:

- static fonts will return multiple URLs - all weights and styles should rather be concatenated
- variable fonts should return valid range tuples - unfortunately **[fontsource API](https://fontsource.org/docs/api/introduction) currently (2023) doesn't include any axes data**. You won't be able to get all axes e.g including `wdth` (width) axis.

### Static fonts

Here's a revised version concatenating all styles and weights in one URL

```js
let fontAPiJsonFS = "https://api.fontsource.org/v1/fonts";
let fontFamily = "Open Sans";
fontFamily = "Roboto";

(async() => {
  let fetched = await fetch(fontAPiJsonFS);
  let fontItems = await (await await fetch(fontAPiJsonFS)).json();

  // filter family name and google fonts
  let fontItem = fontItems.filter(
    (item) => item.family === fontFamily && item.type === "google"
  )[0];
  let url = generateGoogleFontURL(fontItem);
  a_css.href = url;
  a_css.textContent = url;
})();



function generateGoogleFontURL(font) {
  let styles = font.styles;
  let weights = font.weights;
  let hasItalics = styles.includes("italic");
  // very uncommon but might be used for handwriting fonts
  let italicOnly = styles.length === 1 && styles[0] === "italic";
  const formattedFontFamily = font.family.replace(/\s+/g, "+");

  const baseUrl = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=`;
  let url = baseUrl + formattedFontFamily;
  // concatenate prefix like: ":ital,wght@"
  let query_prefix = "";

  /**
   * 1. static fonts
   */

  if (!font.variable) {
    let tuples = [];

    if (hasItalics) {
      query_prefix += ":ital";
      tuples.push(weights.map((x) => `0,${x}`));
    }
    // italics and regular
    if (!italicOnly) {
      query_prefix += ",wght";
      tuples.push(weights.map((x) => `1,${x}`));
    }
    // only regular
    else {
      query_prefix = ":wght";
    }

    // concatenate URL
    url += query_prefix + "@" + tuples.flat().join(";");
    return url;
  } else {

    /**
     * 2. variable fonts
     */
    if (font.weights.length > 1) {
      const minWeight = font.weights[0];
      const maxWeight = font.weights[font.weights.length - 1];

      if (hasItalics) {
        return `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}:ital,wght@0,${minWeight}..${maxWeight};1,${minWeight}..${maxWeight}`;
      } else {
        return `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=${formattedFontFamily}:wght@${minWeight}..${maxWeight}`;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <strong>Google font URL: </strong>
  <a id="a_css" href=""></a>
</p>
```

### Variable fonts

As commented by **Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans**: [google's developer API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api) is currently the better option – at least when it comes to variable fonts.

You'll need to require an [API key](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api#APIKey).
An API call would look like something this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?capability=VF&capability=WOFF2&sort=style&key=${apiKey}
```

It is crucial to add the **capability parameter** `capability=VF` to the query – otherwise the response will omit axes data.

This parameter won't filter the output to variable fonts only!
So you might need to include an extra filter returning only items with an axes property.

#### Common pitfalls: sorting the tuples

Google's open font API is unforgiving about the **order** of tuples (simplified: query chunks).

**google error message**

> Axes must be listed alphabetically (e.g. a,b,c,A,B,C)

They must be sorted in **alphabetical** and **case-sensitive** order

```js
let axes = [
  { tag: "wght", start: 300, end: 800 },
  { tag: "wdth", start: 75, end: 100 },
  { tag: "GRAD", start: -200, end: 150 },
  { tag: "slnt", start: -10, end: 0 }
];


axes = alphanumeric_sort(axes, 'tag');
console.log(axes);


function alphanumeric_sort(object, key) {
  // sort keys alphabetically
  object = object.sort((a, b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]));
  // sort keys case sensitive
  object = [
    object.filter((item) => item[key].toLowerCase() === item[key]),
    object.filter((item) => item[key].toUpperCase() === item[key])
  ].flat();
  return object;
}
```

Now, we can assemble valid CSS URLs including all axes:

```js
let baseUrl = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=`;
let fontAPiJson =
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/herrstrietzel/fonthelpers/main/json/gfontsAPI.json";
let fontFamily = "Roboto Flex";

// init
(async () => {
  let fetched = await fetch(fontAPiJson);
  let fontItems = await (await fetched.json()).items;
  let fontItem = fontItems.filter((item) => item.family === fontFamily)[0];
  //console.log(fontItem)
  let url = baseUrl + getGoogleFontQueryAPI(fontItem, true);
  a_var.href=url;
  a_var.textContent=url;
})();


/**
 * parse API Json
 */
function getGoogleFontQueryAPI(fontItem, variable = true) {
  let fontFamily = fontItem.family;
  // sanitize whitespace in font family name
  let fontfamilyQuery = fontFamily.replaceAll(" ", "+");
  let axes = fontItem.axes;
  let isVF = axes && axes.length ? true : false;
  
  // prepended tuple keys like ital, wght etc
  let queryPre = [];
  let query = "";

  // count weights in variants
  let styles = fontItem.variants;

  // sanitize styles
  styles = styles.map((style) => {
    style = style === "italic" ? "400i" : style;
    return style.replaceAll("italic", "i").replaceAll("regular", "400");
  });

  let weightsItalic = [];
  let weightsRegular = [];
  styles.forEach((style) => {
    if (style.includes("i")) {
      weightsItalic.push(parseFloat(style));
    } else {
      weightsRegular.push(parseFloat(style));
    }
  });

  //  italic and regular
  if (weightsItalic.length) {
    queryPre.push("ital");
  }

  if (weightsRegular.length && !isVF) {
    queryPre.push("wght");
  }

  // is variable
  if (isVF) {
    // sort axes alphabetically - case sensitive ([a-z],[A-Z])!!!
    axes = alphanumeric_sort(axes, 'tag');
    
    let ranges = axes.map((val) => {
      return val.start + ".." + val.end;
    });

    //  italic and regular
    if (weightsItalic.length && weightsRegular.length) {
      //queryPre.push("ital");
      rangeArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        rangeArr.push(`${i},${ranges.join(",")}`);
      }
    }
    // only italic
    else if (weightsItalic.length && !weightsRegular.length) {
      //queryPre.push("ital");
      rangeArr = [];
      rangeArr.push(`1,${ranges.join(",")}`);
    }
    
    // only regular
    else {
      rangeArr = [];
      rangeArr.push(`${ranges.join(",")}`);
    }
    // add axes tags to pre query string
    axes.map((val) => {
      return queryPre.push(val.tag);
    });

    query =
      fontfamilyQuery +
      ":" +
      queryPre.join(",") +
      "@" +
      rangeArr.join(";") +
      "&display=swap";
    return query;
  }

  /**
   * 2. get static
   */
  query = fontfamilyQuery + ":" + queryPre.join(",") + "@";

  // italic and regular
  if (weightsItalic.length && weightsRegular.length) {
    query +=
      weightsRegular
        .map((val) => {
          return "0," + val;
        })
        .join(";") +
      ";" +
      weightsItalic
        .map((val) => {
          return "1," + val;
        })
        .join(";");
  }
  // only italic
  else if (weightsItalic.length && !weightsRegular.length) {
    query += weightsItalic
      .map((val) => {
        return "1," + val;
      })
      .join(";");
  }
  // only regular
  else {
    query += weightsRegular
      .map((val) => {
        return val;
      })
      .join(";");
  }
  return query;
}


function alphanumeric_sort(object, key) {
  // sort keys alphabetically
  object = object.sort((a, b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]));
  // sort keys case sensitive
  object = [
    object.filter((item) => item[key].toLowerCase() === item[key]),
    object.filter((item) => item[key].toUpperCase() === item[key])
  ].flat();
  
  return object;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Variable font URL: </strong><a id="a_var" href=""></a></p>
```

In the above example I'm using a static copy of the output JSON. Some sort of caching is probably a good idea to prevent too many API requests.
However you should update this static copy once in a while to include recently added fonts.

Since [fontsource](https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource) is still quite new (state 2023), you should consider contributing pull requests or suggesting new features in the [discussion](https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource/discussions/) section.

Comment: @StupidDoofus: thanks for accepting this answer. It might be helpful for other users, when (or for which font) your script failed. So please consider adding these info to your question description – save to say: most APIs are a bit quirky ... and will probably change

Comment: I'm not sure about a specific font for which it failed, I think it may just have been due to some rate-limiting on google side, it's just that the error messages were terribly confusing. 
To test if every font worked I just did a naive loop adding every single font in a row, and I was getting random errors after a few hundred fonts.